# How To Fix "Unity CS0101" In Unity Compiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

i have Problem in my unity project. i working in unity 2019.
I Imported Mfps (Multiplayer first person shooter kit) in my project
after i imported MFPS All AddOns.unitypackage (MFPS All Addons package link: https://hitfile.net/2CCivie#) and in my project console i have this error: "Assets\MFPS\Scripts\Internal\Enum\RoundStyle.cs(3,13): error CS0101: The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'RoundStyle'"

i opend the script , This Is Script:
using UnityEngine;

public enum RoundStyle
{
Rounds,
OneMacht
}

i renamed RoundStyle To RoundStyle2 But I got a whole errors

what can i do to solve this error?
Please Help!

Comment: Can you serach for the other occurence of `RoundStyle` ? sounds like something else you built or imported has the same name and since there are no namespaces they all end up in the global unnamed one

Comment: @derHugo yes. but i cant find

Comment: It most probably came together with the MFPS All AddOns .. now the tricky thing is: It might of course sit inside any script together with another class so the script file name doesn't have to match necessarily .. what IDE are you using?

Comment: @derHugo , sorry but i dont know what is IDE And The MFPS, Have so many C# codes i just checking all scripts in this 13 hours and completely

Comment: IDE is the development environment .. like e.g. Visual Studio or Rider etc ... I hope you don't write your code in WordPad ;)

Comment: @derHugo , do you want to send project for you? for some more checking? because I'm new in unity.

Comment: @derHugo , the good news is I'm using visual studio 2019